# How can I merge two vectors?

Tags: c++, vector, merge

I'm developing an application and I want to be more efficient.  In one important part I have 2 large vectors (with the same size) and I merge one in another.  All I want to do is this:

```
std::vector<int> first (4,2); //A vector containing 4 ints with value 2
std::vector<int> second (4,3);  //A vector with 4 ints with value 3

for(int i = first.size()-1; i > 0; --i){

  first[i] += second[i];

}
```

How can I do more efficiently?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you interesting in general solution or compiler specified solution would be enough? If it is, then what compiler do you use?

Comment: @Gluttton woops my bad

Comment: @Eneko These are not vectors they are C arrays. You are not merging them you are adding them member by member.
Concerning your performance issue you could use several optimization methods that would depend on your compiler, and what you know about your data. Loop-unrolling comes to mind.
Most likely you could also use a different container which has built-in optimized algorithms to vectorize such operation.

Comment: @FélixCantournet oh sorry.  I'm working with vectors but actually i've been messed with other code parts and did not write properly. I've edited my question.  So vectors has not built in optimized method for that... I think i should change a flag on the compiler or change the data structures.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For efficient merge several vectors you should use [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) (if your hardware support it).
There are several ways to do it:

- use [inline assembly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_assembler);
- use [intrinsics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function);
- use special classes, which likely use SIMD, like provided in C++11 [std::valarray](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/valarray/);
- use compiler specified [options](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html) and [directives](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html);
- something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multithread, for example. But your arrays should be really big to get profit - starting from about 1,000,000 elements

Answer (score 0):

You may find this method faster:

```
int main()
{
    int first = {5, 10, 15, 20, 25};
    int second = {50, 40, 30, 20, 10};

    int* f = first;
    int* e = first + (sizeof(first)/sizeof(int));
    int* s = second;

    while(f != e)
        *f++ += *s++;

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(first)/sizeof(int); ++i)
        std::cout << " " << first[i];
}
```

Comment: @FélixCantournet In my basic tests this was well over 2 times faster. And the question was asking for faster, not readable. But I recommend people do their own bench marks in case I missed something.

Comment: Fair enough, it will be a little faster. However I think that the OP is looking for SIMD kind of optimization rather than this. cf Gluttton's answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    int first[] = {5,10,15,20,25};
    int second[] = {50,40,30,20,10};
    int len=first.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < second.size(); i++,len++)
    {
        first[len]= second[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add an explanation to your answer...  it seems you didn't address the efficiency question but instead changed the code to do an actual merge where before he was adding the elements together.